# Change a badge icon image in ios 4?[Close]

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

**Question**

How can I change the badge icon image in ios4? I would like it to look like this:

[image: Badge Icon Image]

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Your only option is to submit an app update with the new icon. Of course your will need to submit another update to change the icon again.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. iOS puts the new ribbon there. The developer cannot control that.

Comment: This application change badge icon

Comment: You can't change the badge programmatically. Only iOS can add the new ribbon.